# get a char that does not wait for input

Tags: input, char, ncurses, 2d-games, conio

I'm building a menu for a game using ncurses.h. In this part, I want a blinking text to be on screen and, only exit that loop, if the user press any key. In conio.h, I used this (was not perfect):

```
void start()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        gotoxy(32, 18 - i);
        printf("1024");
        Sleep(200);
        clrscr();
    }

    gotoxy(32, 8);
    printf("1024");
    gotoxy (35, 18);

    while (!kbhit())            

    {
        textcolor(15);          
        gotoxy (15, 15);
        printf("Press any key to continue...");

        if (kbhit() != 0)                                   

        Sleep(1000);
        textcolor(0);           
        gotoxy (15, 15);
        printf("Aperte qualquer tecla para continuar...");

        if (kbhit() != 0)
            break;

        Sleep(500);

        if (kbhit() != 0)
            break;

    }

    textcolor(15);
    fflush(stdin);
    clrscr();

}
```

In ncurses.h, I'm trying to do the same thing, but the getch() seems to wait for the user imput, therefore "pausing" the execution.

```
void start()
{
    int i, ch = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
        move(18 - i, 32);
        printw("1024");
        refresh();
        usleep(200 * 1000);
        clear();
        refresh();
    }

    move(18, 35);

    while (1)
    {
        if (getch() != 0)
            break;

        attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
        move(15, 15);

        printw("Aperte qualquer tecla para continuar...");
        refresh();

        usleep(1000 * 1000);
        clear();
        refresh();
        move(15, 15);
        printw("Aperte qualquer tecla para continuar...");

        usleep(500 * 1000);

    }

    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));
    system("clear");

}
```

Solutions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With ncurses (any curses implementation), you can get single-character-input by calling [`cbreak`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-cbreak) during initialization (see the manual page section on [Initialization](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization)).

Also, I'd use [`napms`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-napms) rather than `usleep`.

Since your program is using `getch`, expecting to just *poll*, you might want to use [`timeout`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-timeout_wtimeout) or [`nodelay`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nodelay) and ignore cases where `getch` returns **`ERR`**.  For example

```
cbreak();    /* control/C will kill the program */
timeout(10); /* 10 milliseconds is a good compromise */
while (1)
{
    if (getch() == ERR)
        continue;  /* ignore, timeout expired with nothing read */
```

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but I don't know how to use timeout or nodelay for my specific problem. Is that to exit that loop if the user doens't press anything in a x amount of time?

If, so I still want to try to be in that loop indefinitely until the user press something...

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Here's what I got untik now: 

`while(1)
    {
        wattron(win, COLOR_PAIR(CONTINUE_START_ON));
        mvwprintw(win, 18, 25, "Press any key to continue");
        wrefresh(win);
        napms(1000);
        wattron(win, COLOR_PAIR(CONTINUE_START_OFF));
        mvwprintw(win, 18, 25, "Press any key to continue");
        wrefresh(win);
        napms(1000);

        timeout(10);
        if(getch() == ERR)
            break;
    }`

Comment: breaking on timeout won't be helpful, since the loop will exit after 1 second.